# I can't reinstall civicrm "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, installation

I installed civicrm on Wordpress without the test data so I just wanted to uninstall it by deactivating + deleting the folders .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm & wp-content/uploads/civicrm

I also can't find the civicrm.setting.php so I might uninstalled it rightfully.

But whenever, after activating, I try to install civicrm I get the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you also delete all tables prefixed with `civicrm_`

Comment: not yet how do I do it without making seperate DROP TABLE <...> Statements;

Comment: You can use `DROP TBLE` statements or if you have a GUI like phpmyadmin available you can use that.   You will have to drop the tables to re-install.